# Propose 'android-honeycomb' is synonym of 'android-3.0' tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

I propose that the [android-honeycomb](/questions/tagged/android-honeycomb) tag be marked/configured as a synonym of the [android-3.0](/questions/tagged/android-3.0) tag, since honeycomb is just the codename for Android 3.0.

Is someone with sufficient permission (more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag) please able to suggest this synonym for others to vote on?

Comment: You should precise on which site(s), Stack Overflow, Android.SE or both.

Comment: I assumed that meta.stackoverflow.com was just for stackoverflow.com.  I don't even know what Android.SE is.  http://android.se doesn't look related to stackoverflow.com... Ah, I see it's http://android.stackexchange.com.  At any rate, this synonym proposal is for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: It is not a synonym.  Version 3.1 is still called Honeycomb.

Comment: That is not true.  Version 3.1 is Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: Is `honeycomb` somehow ambiguous?  Why are you editing it to `android-honeycomb`?

Comment: Why have both?  Pick one.  I did.

Comment: Please bring it up here on Meta before making that many tag edits.  We have tools we can use to merge tags in one action so you don't have to spend your time doing it manually.

Comment: I have another itch.  New post in a minute...

Comment: @Programmer: That is not correct, 3.1 has already been released and it is still Honeycomb. They did not change the name for 3.1.

Comment: Unexpectedly confirmed.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comments, "Honeycomb" is in fact the codename for not just Android release 3.0, but also for Android release 3.1.  (I misunderstood this point during the Google I/O announcements.)

So, Moderators, please don't hesitate to close this request.